# Why should I use @Url.Content("~/blah-blah-blah")?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can't understand the benefit(s) that I can get from [`Url.Content()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx) method in ASP.NET MVC. For example, you see `src='@Url.Content("~/Contents/Scripts/jQuery.js")'`. Why should I use it? What reasons might exist for using it? What benefits, advantages, etc. over using plain old simple references like `src='/scripts/jquery.js`?

**Update:** Based on the answers, I'd like to know if there is any other reason for using it, other than handling virtual folders? Because I haven't seen using virtual applications that much (which of course doesn't mean that it hasn't been used that much).

Comment: You've never had multiple applications existing under a single website

Comment: Well, is that the only reason they use `@Url.Content`? If so, can we simply stop using it on one-application per website solutions?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - its always best to include it. You never know how the site structure may change in the future. Technically though if you _never_ would change its location and its one app per website with no virtual directories underneath it, etc then sure you could just use src='/scripts/whatever.js'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Mapping virtual paths is its only purpose.
If you do not ever need to map them and are sure your app or it folders will not sit under other apps then it won't serve you any purpose.

From [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.iurlhelper.content), note that, if you don't use `~`, you get no change in the result anyway:

> If the specified content path does not start with the tilde (~) character, this method returns contentPath unchanged.

Comment: Also note that in MVC4 some of this is handled automatically, for example a script tag you can just specify src="~/scripts/whatever.js" and razor will automatically map it for you now without the use of url.content

Answer (score 34):

Usually, your web application is published as: `www.yoursite.com/`. The `~` character matches the root of the site, `/`.

However, if you publish your site withing a virtual directory `www.yoursite.com/mywebapp/`, then the `~` character would match `/mywebapp/`.
Hard-coding URLs with the "/" character would cause incorrect page references.

Answer (score 16):

It is usefull if your applications root path is not the root path of your server. Url.Content("~/") returns the root folder of your application.

Comment: From what I'm experiencing. using `~` shows no image content when you hover over the link in visual studio. Says couldn't locate [path].