# "~" and "/" Not giving the root folder on asp.net-mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

On a shared view (like _layout.cshtml), I'm asking for the root folder in many ways (`"/Content/design.css"`, `@Url.Content("~/Content/design.css")` ) But I'm always getting the controller name and then the requested url ("localhost:3333/MyControllerName/Content/design.css")

Why?

I'm running my project on IIS express.

This is the problematic line:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/design.css")" />
```

also tried:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("/Content/design.css")" />
```

Comment: Can you post some of the offending view. Are you running the application on IIS with this result?

Comment: I'm not sure what u mean by "offending view"

Comment: post the code for view that the Url.Content line is on

Comment: The view that is having the issue resolving the root application path. `Url.Content("~...` should take care of it for you.

Comment: Looks like it should work but have you tried `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/design.css" />`.  According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468987/why-should-i-use-url-content-blah-blah-blah @Url.Content has a specific purpose and you might not even need it.

Comment: That's quite odd. What's the value when you try `System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/design.css")`?

Comment: I agree with @Ben, this is undo .NET fluff. OR just use the bundle, and make sure that css file is in it. ex. @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

Comment: @BenRobinson - I tried, its not working

Comment: @Shahar I'm not sure what you mean by not working are you saying even if you use a static HTML link then something somehow changes the href?  Or does it not work in some other manner?

Comment: @StevenV - the result: "/Content/design.css"

Comment: @BenRobinson when I use a static html link, the "/" is pointed to localhost:2222/MyControllerName/
This means that it might be IIS responsible for that?

Comment: @hubsonbropa when I use a static html link, the "/" is pointed to localhost:2222/MyControllerName/ This means that it might be IIS responsible for that?

Comment: I imagine its doing this because of the route configuration you have, not sure what that is, but the app controls what controller is brought up based on that. I suggest you add your css file to the style bundle and use @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you fixed this, I know I'm late, can you try this?
I'm thinking you don't need `@Url.Content`

```
<link href="~/Content/design.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```