# ASP.NET MVC 4 site returns 404 for image

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I think this might be a routing issue, but I am not sure how to fix.

I have an image at...

```
<img src="/blog/images/scheduleAutoCalculation1.png">
```

and have verified it exists in that path.  It should pull up.  However, it returns a 404.

If I copy the image and load it with

```
<img src="/Resources/scheduleAutoCalculation1.png">
```

it pulls up fine.  Here is my route table...

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why I am getting a 404 for the first link?

Also, I don't have a BlogController class, so it is not trying to route to that (maybe it is??).  The site is simple with only two controllers HomeController and StyleController.

Comment: Off topic: my advice is to use `<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/test.png")" />` or just `<img src="~/Content/...." />`. It converts a relative path into an absolute, see this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468987/why-should-i-use-url-content-blah-blah-blah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to load images from another Views type of folder I had created.  The web.config located in that directory was blocking the request.  I moved the images to another folder and it works fine.