# View in MVC4 not rendering properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

When calling a controller action like this:

controller/action

everything works great. But when calling the same action with a id-parameter like:

controller/action/id

ex. home/index/10

the view seems not to render according to mu css-file....

Anyone that know anything about this??

Call:

```
<INPUT class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Last" onclick="window.location.href = '/Home/Statistics/4'">
```

Action

```
public ActionResult Statistics(string id)
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Variables.logInStatusAvtiveUser = "notActive";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Home()
        {
            if (Variables.logInStatusAvtiveUser == "active")
            {
                string[] nameCampain = { "Omega3", "VitaminC", "VitaminD" };
                string[] doublets = { "34", "22", "21" };
                string[] customer = { "21", "12", "11" };
                string[] hit = { "2", "4", "6" };
                string[] nonValid = { "11", "12", "13" };
                string[] batch = { "30", "40", "20" };
                string[] batchActual = { "30", "40", "20" };
                string[] total = { "30", "40", "20" };
                string[] totalActual = { "30", "40", "20" };
                string[] feedBackActual = { "30", "40", "20" };
                ViewBag.chart = CToHTML.CreateHTMLChart(nameCampain, doublets, customer, hit, nonValid, batch, batchActual, total, totalActual, feedBackActual);
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Database()
        {   
            if (Variables.logInStatusAvtiveUser == "active")
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult Statistics(string id) 
        {
            if (Variables.logInStatusAvtiveUser == "active")
            {
                string q = "`Name`,`Family Name`,`Gender`,`Zip Code`,`Town`,`Adress`";
                MySqlBinding dbConn = new MySqlBinding(Variables.serverActiveUser, Variables.portActiveUser, Variables.databaseActiveUser, Variables.usernameActiveUser, Variables.passwordActiveUser);

                if (id == "1")
                {
                    ViewBag.DB = CToHTML.ConvertDataTableToHTML(dbConn.SelectFromDT(Variables.databaseActiveUser, "Leads", q, "0", "50"));
                }
                if (id == "2")
                {
                    ViewBag.DB = CToHTML.ConvertDataTableToHTML(dbConn.SelectFromDT(Variables.databaseActiveUser, "Leads", q, "50", "100"));
                }
                if (id == "3")
                {
                    ViewBag.DB = CToHTML.ConvertDataTableToHTML(dbConn.SelectFromDT(Variables.databaseActiveUser, "Leads", q, "100", "150"));
                }
                if (id == "4")
                {
                    ViewBag.DB = CToHTML.ConvertDataTableToHTML(dbConn.SelectFromDT(Variables.databaseActiveUser, "Leads", q, "150", "200"));
                }
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }   

    }
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>Sticky Footer Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <%@ Import Namespace="CAIUGO_UI_BOOTSTRAP_V2" %>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
      </head>

  <body>

      <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <!-- Wrap all page content here -->
    <div id="wrap">

      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CAIUGO</a>
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="Home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="Database">Database</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="Statistics">Statistics</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
        <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 100px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 10%"> </td>
                <td style="width: 60%"> </td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    <div class="pull-right">                    
                        <INPUT class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="First" onclick="window.location.href = '/Home/Statistics/1'">
                        <INPUT class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="<-" onclick="window.location.href = '/Home/Statistics/2'">
                        <INPUT class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="->" onclick="window.location.href = '/Home/Statistics/3'">
                        <INPUT class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Last" onclick="window.location.href = '/Home/Statistics/4'">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 10%"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table style="width: 100%">

            <tr>
                <td style="width: 10%">&nbsp;</td>

                <% dataTable.InnerHtml = ViewBag.DB;%>
                <td id="dataTable" runat="server">&nbsp;

                       <%-- Autocreated HTML Table here --%>

                </td>
                <td style="width: 10%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>

      <!-- Begin page content -->

<div style="height: auto; width: 80%">

</div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">



      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your view controller and view please.

Comment: *the view seems not to render according to mu css-file....* - please elaborate on this.

Comment: The view looks like i dint use any css file at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the css is not applied it means css file is not loaded because it can be due to css file url issue, what you need to do is to use `@Url.Content()` helper for css and js file include like this:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet">
```

and js file as well:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
```

and ico icon as well:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="@Url.Content("~/docs-assets/ico/favicon.png")">
```

this approach should be applied on img tags as well in the views, otherwise you will experience that sometimes images will also not load because of wrong url.

this will generate the correct url from the relative url to load the css and js in the view.

you can see here, why to use it:

[Why should I use @Url.Content("~/blah-blah-blah")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468987/why-should-i-use-url-content-blah-blah-blah)

and here is [**MSDN docs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I dint actually get it to work with the Url.content(im nor using Razor)                                                              But by putting ../../ instead of only ../ it worked...