# How to display icon as a value on a Kendo Grid cell?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, datagridview, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a table called Priority and it has a column called IconUrl that is used to store the path of the icons as shown below:

```
| ID     | Priority      | IconUrl       
------------------------------------------------------------| 
| 0      | Normal        | /../../Content/icons/normal.png  |
| 1      | Urgent        | /../../Content/icons/urgent.png  |
| 2      | Blocker       | /../../Content/icons/blocker.png |
```

I want to display icons according to the IconUrl values for each records on the Kendo Grid. I tried some methods as shown below, but none of them was solved the problem yet. How to manage to display just icon images?

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Priority).ClientTemplate("<img src='" + Url.Content("~/") + "#=IconUrl#' height='62' width='62'/>");
```

or

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Priority).ClientTemplate("<img src='" + Url.Content("#=Model.IconUrl#") + "'/>'");
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be caused by the `'/../../'` at the start of your url.

Open your browsers developer tools, look at the cell can see what url is there.

If your content folder is in your home or project directory then recreating the url with the text from `Priority` col might work.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Priority).ClientTemplate("<img src='" + Url.Content("~/Content/icons/") + "#=Priority.toLowerCase()#.png' height='62' width='62'/>");
```

The [Url.Content function is used to map virtual paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468987/why-should-i-use-url-content-blah-blah-blah). For example having apps inside other apps. If there is not a tilde at the start of the string passed to the function it will just return the url string unchanged.

So in your second example calling `"<img src='" +Url.Content("#=IconUrl#") + "'/>'"` will produce the same result as `<a src='#=IconUrl#'>`

Comment: Actually the problem was caused by syntax in the html, rather than **/../../** (I had already tried with several form of this). So, the icons can be displayed by using `columns.Bound(c => c.PriorityDescription).ClientTemplate(@"<div class='grid-icon' style='background-image: url(#:data.IconUrl#);'></div>").Width("40px");` Thanks a lot. Voted+.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on [Grid / Basic usage](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/index) on Telerik page, you can display the image as shown below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CustomerViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.PriorityDescription)
           .ClientTemplate(@"<div class='grid-icon' style='background-image: 
                url(#:data.IconUrl#);'></div>").Width("40px");
        columns.Bound(c => c.ContactTitle).Width(190);
        columns.Bound(c => c.CompanyName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Country).Width(110);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(true)
        .ButtonCount(5))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Grid"))
    )
)


<style>
.customer-photo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 32px 35px;
    background-position: center center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 32px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #999, inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.customer-name {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
</style>
```