# JavaScript File Path Issue/Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

My pictures are in this path:

```
Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assests/pages/media/bg/1.jpg
Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assests/pages/media/bg/2.jpg
Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assests/pages/media/bg/3.jpg
Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assests/pages/media/bg/4.jpg
```

I did the same path in my .js files:

```
..Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/1.jpg
..Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/2.jpg
..Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/3.jpg
..Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/4.jpg
```

But when I run the page then click F12 I get an error like below:

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmQ47.png)

How can I fix this issue?

---

Edit:
I change my .js files path like this:

```
../Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/1.jpg
../Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/2.jpg
../Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/3.jpg
../Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/4.jpg
```

And this is the error:

[New Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTtcA.png)

Comment: where is the js file inside your server?

Comment: Add `/` to `..Areas`. Should be: `../Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/1.jpg`. Or to root: `/Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/1.jpg`.

Comment: @Danny Fardy Jhonston Bermúdez Can you check my edit please?

Comment: Can you try with this: `../Content/assets/pages/media/bg/4.jpg`?

Comment: I suggest you start [using virtual paths and the `@Url.Content` helper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10468987/215552). They make relative URLs much easier to think about, especially when using areas.

Answer (score 0):

First mistake is lack of backslash after points `../Areas`.
Second it depends on your root directory of server.
How did you create server? Is the server NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with this path:

```
/Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/1.jpg
/Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/2.jpg
/Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/3.jpg
/Areas/YonetimPaneli/Content/assets/pages/media/bg/4.jpg
```