# How to change root path ~/ in Razor in asp.net core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application with Razor that widely uses the `~/path` syntax.

Everything works great if the application runs from the domain root (for example, from `http://localhost:5000/`)

But when I run the application at a non-root location (for example, `http://localhost:5000/app`), Razor still uses root (`/`) as the base path.

How can I configure this? I want to specify a base path for Razor's `~/`? There must be an environment variable for it.

PS: the application is run in Docker behind the reverse proxy.

Comment: How are you using *"~/"* ? You should look to use [`@Url.Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.urlhelper.content?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Routing_UrlHelper_Content_System_String_) to handle virtual directories. See [why-should-i-use-url-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468987/why-should-i-use-url-content-blah-blah-blah)

Comment: Hmm, I thought those are the same things, and Razor converts ~\ to Url.Content calls. But thanks, I will try to replace and see what’d happen.

Comment: Did you have any luck with using `@Url.Content`?

Comment: No, the same thing :(

Answer (score 12):

In your "Startup" class in the "Configure" method use next:

```
app.UsePathBase("/yourBasePath");
```

Comment: This solution also works with minimal APIs.

Comment: Is this still the right way in .NET 6?  I've tried it but no luck.

Comment: @Anish See [this other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155917/how-to-change-root-path-in-razor-in-asp-net-core/70610242#70610242) which suggests in .NET 6 to use `app.UseRouting();` as well.

Answer (score 3):

For .NET Core 3.1, I used `context.Request.PathBase` as following:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.Scheme = schemeValue;
    #if !DEBUG
    context.Request.PathBase = $"/{applicationOptions.BasePath}";
    #endif
    return next();
});
```

Comment: This solution worked for me on RazorPages .NET 6 while the UsePathBase middleware didn't work

Answer (score 3):

.NET 6 you need to apped `app.UseRouting();` also like

```cs
var app = builder.Build();

app.UsePathBase("/SomeBasePath");

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

from milestone: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38448

pd: Default route still works
so users can hit:

```
/SomeBasePath/api
/api
```

workaround idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69859449/11813109 not tested

**This is .NET 7 milestone so we just need to wait for documentation and fixes.**