# Default URL in net6 web apps

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm porting a net core 2.1 web app to net 6 and hitting a problem with the root url of the app.  In 2.1, I set the root url in launchSettings.json eg

```
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001/toolbox",
  "sslPort": 0
}
```

In net 6 that throws an error (you can't have "/toolbox" in applicationUrl) and I'm instructed to use app.UseBasePath in program.cs, thus

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UsePathBase("/toolbox");
```

That works.  I can hit my app at localhost:5001/toolbox.

But I can also hit it at localhost:5001.  Is there a way to restrict access such that the app only responds to localhost:5001/toolbox ?

Comment: You can try attribute routing. Check this https://www.infoworld.com/article/3569369/how-to-use-attribute-routing-in-aspnet-core.html

Comment: You can use Endpoint redirect extension as well.. Check https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/simple-redirects-with-aspnet-core-endpoint-routing

Comment: @ChinmayT -  I'm wanting to *prevent* a route rather than make one (if that makes sense?!).

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2698) github discussion `UsePathBase` is not supposed to restrict the usage of root path. If you want to do that you can do something like that:

```cs
public class RestrictingUsePathBaseMiddleware
{
    private readonly PathString pathBase;
    private readonly UsePathBaseMiddleware usePathBaseMiddleware;

    public RestrictingUsePathBaseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, PathString pathBase)
    {
        this.pathBase = pathBase;
        usePathBaseMiddleware =new UsePathBaseMiddleware(next, pathBase);
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(pathBase, out var matchedPath, out var remainingPath))
        {
            return usePathBaseMiddleware.Invoke(context);
        }

        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound; // do what is appropriate with the Response
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public static class RestrictingUsePathBaseExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseRestrictingPathBase(this IApplicationBuilder app, PathString pathBase)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        }

        pathBase = pathBase.Value?.TrimEnd('/');
        if (!pathBase.HasValue)
        {
            return app;
        }

        return app.UseMiddleware<RestrictingUsePathBaseMiddleware>(pathBase);
    }
}
```

And change `app.UsePathBase("/api");` to `app.UseRestrictingPathBase("/api");` (note that all middlewares registered before it will still run successfully).